# Numpy not broadcasting together compatible shapes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

The following code gives an error for me in Python 3.8.3:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(10, 5, 2)
b = np.random.rand(10, 5)
c = a/b
```

with error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,5,2) (10,5)
```

But these two shapes should be compatible, right? I can get the division to work by using b[:, :, None], but the [Numpy page on broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) doesn't give any indication that this extra syntax should be necessary. Maybe I'm going crazy, but I could have sworn that I've written code like this before and not had any errors. What am I missing here?

Comment: `(10,5,1)` is compatible with `a`.  But broadcasting can't do that; to avoid ambiguity it can only add leading dimensions, e.g. `(1,10,5)`.

Answer (score 0):

To broadcast you need to extend the dimension, something like `(10,5,2)` and `(10,5,1)`. That said, you should do:

```
c = a/b[...,None]
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy (automatically) broadcasts to the left but not to the right. That is why your code gives an error

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(10, 5, 2)
b = np.random.rand(10, 5)
c = a / b  # gives error
```

while this code works

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(10, 5, 2)
b = np.random.rand(5, 2)
c = a / b
print('shape of c', c.shape)
```

which gives

```
shape of c (10, 5, 2)
```

So use the suggested solution or one of the alternatives:

```
a = np.random.rand(10, 5, 2)
b = np.random.rand(10, 5)
c = a / b[..., None]
c = a / b[..., np.newaxis]
c = a / b[:, :, None]
c = a / b[:, :, np.newaxis]
```